# Git pull request has all the deleted files in Files Changed

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I created a new branch named 'week04-submissions', which had all the folders and files from the main branch, I deleted those folders and files and created a new folder named week04 and pushed new files in this folder. Now when I created a new pull request, to merge this branch to main, now all those previously the deleted files are shown in the Files Changed tab, with their deleted status.

I don't want the reviewer to see the deleted files status.

[image]

Comment: I see two sides to this question.... first, so... you added/committed the deletion locally... and you want it to not show up in the commit? Then you should **not** have added/committed said deletion... the commit is what it is. You could have kept the delition locally without adding/committing it.... which takes me to the second point: If you meant to have in your working tree only a subset of the project, then you should use `sparse checkout`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Comment: Yeah, I might have deleted the files locally and then committed, that's why the deletion is tracked.
Now to resolve this issue, should reset to that commit or before that?

Comment: And most important, if you merge that PR, the files are "gone" from your main branch. that's why they MUST be shown as deleted in the PR.

Comment: When a commit (branch, "pull request") is merged ("pulled"), it means "take all the changes that the other side made since it forked and apply them to this side". Since you made a change -- you deleted files --, these changes are applied. That is the way it is intended. If you do not want that the files get deleted, then don't delete them. It's as simple as that.

Comment: You can run `git rebase -i the-base-branch` and it will list the commits that make up your PR... on the commit where you deleted the files, set it to `edit` instead of `pick`. Save and exit. Git will stop right after applying that commit... get the files back with `git restore --source HEAD~ --worktree --staged -- path-to-files-that-were-deleted`. Files should be added now in index... then `git commit --amend --no-edit`. Then if everything looks fine (as if the files had not been deleted), run `git rebase --continue`.